# How to add NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged to a Observable FromEventPattern

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have started to learn Rx recently and tried playing with event to Rx conversion. I tried creating Network Observable in Window Phone 8 using NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged event.

But when I add NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged using Observable.FromEventPattern like below:

```
var networkInformationStatus = Observable.FromEventPattern(typeof(NetworkInformation), "NetworkStatusChanged");

networkInformationStatus.Subscribe(x => 
            {
                txtClickdata.Text = string.Format("Is internet connected: {0}", NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable());
                txtClickdata2.Text = string.Format("Network type: {0}", NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType);
            });
```

This is giving me following error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? How to add this event to Observable?

Comment: Another point is that you should be using the instance of your `NetworkInformation` class and not `typeof(NetworkInformation)` when creating the observable.

Comment: @Enigmativity it's a static class, and the event is declared static as well, so I believe that is the correct usage if the event conformed to the standard `EventArg` Pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the documentation on the method you are using it says that it is only for

> events conforming to the standard .NET event pattern with a System.EventArgs parameter

`NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged` is a non-standard event type so you need to use the `FromEvent` with the conversion overload.

```
        Observable.FromEvent<NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler, object>(
            emit => new NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler(
                                 (target) => emit(target)),
            h => NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += h, 
            h => NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged -= h);
```

This will allow Rx to properly convert the incoming event.

Comment: I will suggest renaming the parameter in your first lambda from `conversion` to `emit`.  The conversion is the lambda - the first argument to `Observable.FromEvent`. The *argument to that lambda* is an action which emits a value to all subscribers of the observable, not a conversion. Your first lambda would be `emit => new NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler(emit)`.

Comment: The reason renaming this is important is that the `Observable.FromEvent` method is already very confusing to people.